# How to upload a file in a Rails Rspec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to test uploading a file in a Rails Rspec request test.  I'm using Paperclip for asset storage.

I've tried:

```
path = 'path/to/fixture_file'
params = { file: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path, 'application/pdf', true) }
post v1_product_documents_path, params: params
```

In the controller, I get a string

> "#Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x0055b544479128>"

instead of the actual file.

The same code works in controller tests

Answer (score 19):

try to use **fixture_file_upload**:
[fixture_file_upload](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/TestProcess.html#method-i-fixture_file_upload)

or
 if you wanted to use this in a factory

```
 Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/images/bob-weir.jpg')))
```

Comment: `fixutre_file_upload` uses `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` under the hood, so this is generally identical.

Answer (score 13):

In rails_helper.rb do

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
include Rack::Test::Methods
```

Then you have few options. 
1. You can use [fixture_file_upload](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload) helper

```
  let(:file) { fixture_file_upload('files/image.jpg') }
  it 'it should work' do
    post some_path, params: { uploads: { file: file } }
  end
```

2. You can use Uploaded file but you have to give full path

```
  let(:file) { Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec',
  'fixtures', 'blank.jpg'), 'image/jpg') }
  let(:params) { { attachment: file, variant_ids: ['', product.master.id] } }
  let(:action) { post :create, product_id: product.slug, image: params }
```

Comment: I don't think this has any practical difference from RSB's answer.

Answer (score 7):

For rails 6 no need to do includes, just `fixture_file_upload`. If you are using `spec/fixtures/files` folder for fixtures you can use `file_fixture` helper

```
let(:csv_file) { fixture_file_upload(file_fixture('file_example.csv')) }

subject(:http_request) { post upload_file_path, params: { file: csv_file } }
```

Answer (score 4):

Under `describe` block, include these modules

```
include Rack::Test::Methods
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
```

Now try running the specs

```
path = 'path/to/fixture_file'
params = { "file" => Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(path, 'application/pdf', true) }
post v1_product_documents_path, params: params
```

Also, I guess you forgot to add `,` between `v1_product_documents_path` and `params: params`, please add that and let me know.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Those two includes don't seem to help (I had tried that before). Were you able to gets this working in a Rails request spec?

Comment: @hirowatari you did put the includes within the `describe` block?

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful for other users: I got this problem because I mistakenly used a `get` instead of a `post` request in my specs.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue while writing request specs for a POST endpoint that processes incoming email payloads that include file attachments.

this is what the request looked like in the request spec:

```
post api_v1_email_processor_path, params: params, as: :json
```

where `params[:attachment]` was:

```
fixture_file_upload("spec/support/fixtures/files/report.csv", 'text/csv',)
```

and when I added some breakpoints in the controller, this is what the attachment was being converted into:

```
{"original_filename"=>"report.csv", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x0000000121d2bfc8>", "content_type"=>"text/csv"}
```

as you can see, the `"tempfile"` was being cast to a string value of `"<File:0x0000000121d2bfc8>"`

when I emulated the same request in a *controller* spec, to my huge confusion, there was no casting, and the breakpoint showed the param (correctly) as:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000012d559488 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/jg/n_0rknb97kvddb0jgh6r3_x40000gn/T/RackMultipart20221008-45122-mzyqg5.csv>, @original_filename="report.csv", @content_type="text/csv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment1\"; filename=\"report.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\nContent-Length: 24931\r\n">]
```

after seeing L.Youl's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67987482/14926068, it got me thinking that the issue was with how the request payload was being formatted, prior to being sent to the server through the Rack middleware.  and so I tried taking off the `as: :json`:

```
post api_v1_email_processor_path, params: params
```

and bingo, I got the same result as with the controller spec.

after inspecting `response.request.content_type` in my request spec, I found that when I took the `as: :json` off, its value changed from `"application/json"` to

```
"multipart/form-data; boundary=----------XnJLe9ZIbbGUYtzPQJ16u1"
```

for completeness, I checked `response.request.content_type` in the controller spec as well, and found that even with `as: :json` in the request, the `content_type` was being set to `"multipart/form-data"`, and that accounted for the discrepancy in behavior between controller and request specs - it seems that `as: :json` only affects the `"content-type"` in the request specs.

in retrospect, it was obvious - json cannot be used to send actual files.  but it took me a long time to figure it out because the equivalent controller spec was working fine and this was literally the only endpoint in my Rails api-only app that expected non-json payloads

Answer (score 0):

For others still getting something like `"#Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x0055b544479128>"` in the controller after implementing the approved solution above, I resolved this by changing my `content-type` header to be `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` so that form data would be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
 file = File.expand_path("path/to/fixture_file", __dir__)
 Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(file, 'application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `content type` in your RSpec test, it seems you can pass it as an argument to `fixture_file_upload` (no idea why this method does not derive the content type from the OS).

For instance:

```rb
fixture_file_upload("pdfs/some.pdf", "application/pdf")
```