# How to Simulate ActiveStorage Uploads in RSpec Request Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I'm writing an API-Only Rails App (rails 5.2) and I need to make use of ActiveStorage. I want to write an RSpec Request Spec to ensure that file uploads work properly, but that's proving very difficult. Here's my spec so far:

```rb
RSpec.describe 'POST /profile/photos', type: :request do
  let(:url) { '/profile/photos' }
  let(:file) { fixture_file_upload('photo.jpg') }

  before do
    log_user_in

    ## Do a file upload ##
    post '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads', params: {
      blob: {
        filename: "woman.jpg",
        content_type: "image/jpeg",
        byte_size: File.size(file.path),
        checksum:  Digest::MD5.base64digest(File.read(file.path))
      }
    }

    post url, params: {signed_id: json["signed_id"]}
  end

  it "Performs an upload" do
    # Never gets here, error instead
  end
end
```

I've tried using the `put` helper to upload the file between the first and second `post` call in the `before` step, but I keep running into 422 unprocessable entity errors, likely because the `put` helper doesn't support setting the raw request body. But I'm not entirely sure what the format of that put should be, or if there's a better way to test this.

I've tried using `fixture_file_upload`, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796140/how-to-upload-a-file-in-a-rails-rspec-request-spec):

```rb
put json["direct_upload"]["url"], params: {file: fixture_file_upload('photo.jpg')}
```

But that request returns 422 like all of my other attempts. I think the direct_upload URL really wants the body of the request to contain the file and nothing else.

I suspect there's a lot wrong with my approach here, but the Rails docs are somewhat sparse on how to use ActiveStorage if you're not using the out-of-the-box javascript to hide most of the interactions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably don't care about testing the Active Storage engine so you don't need to `post '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads'`, you just need a valid signature.

I ended up creating an `ActiveStorage::Blob` by hand and then I can ask it for the signature. Something like this off in a helper:

```
def blob_for(name)
  ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
    io: File.open(Rails.root.join(file_fixture(name)), 'rb'),
    filename: name,
    content_type: 'image/jpeg' # Or figure it out from `name` if you have non-JPEGs
  )
end
```

and then in your specs you can say:

```
post url, params: { signed_id: blob_for('photo.jpg').signed_id }
```

Comment: I realized after seeing this answer that I was also hoping to validate the ActiveStorage web API so I can feel good about linking up an arbitrary front-end to it. This does perfectly test that my controller is accepting the signed_ids properly, though.